# How do I execute a method every time a tab is pressed from the tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates, tabbar

I want to run a method every time a tab from the tab bar is pressed in my app. How do I do this? I have a tab bar controller in my storyboard (built when i chose tab bar application when I created the project).

For example I want to print 'tab button pressed to the console every time a tab button is pressed.

I tried adding this in the app delegate without any luck:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

    NSLog(@"Tab Button Pressed");

}
```

This is probably quite simple but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xcode 4.2.x then the templates set up the `UITabBarController` in code in the `appDelegate`

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;    //<---- Add this line
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

If you have an old style project or built your structure using interface builder then:

1. Right click the `Tab bar controller` in the objects view
2. Locate the `delegate` outlet
3. Connect the `delegate` outlet to the `File's Owner`

[image]
[image]

Comment: What a fantastic answer. I learned so much from this post, thanks! My first app will be in the store in no time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set your view controller to be the delegate for the tab bar?

Comment: ah no, that sound like it's what I want though. Do i do that in IB or using code?

Comment: You can do either.  Code's easy - myTabView.delegate = self; (where self is your view controller)

Comment: I'm stuck. The tab bar controller was built when i selected the tab bar project when i started the app. What do you mean by set the view controller to be the delegate?